# Insertar una imagen en base de datos con vue.js y asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js, asp.net-core

Quiero insertar una imagen en mi proyecto, la trabajo con una api de **asp.net core** con **vue.js** para la vista, la cosa es que no he encontrado un como hacerlo.

Intente con un bit, pero solo me salen ejemplos de asp.net, osea sin vue.js, en la base puse la variable tipo image, entity me lo puso tipo bit en el Api, pero no logro enviarla desde el vue.

Este es mi input

```
             <v-form enctype="multipart/form-data" xs12>
              <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="imagen" />
            </v-form>
```

Así intento enviarla desde el vue.js:

```
Imagen : this.imagen,
```

para comentar, uso axios para conectar con el asp.net

```
Imagen = model.Imagen,
```

Digamos que así, intento meterlo a la base, pero he visto que es un método gigante pero no logro realizar, me podrían ayudar o no saben un articulo o libro?

Comment: Si entiendo correctamente, ¿Quieres enviar una imagen por POST a una api hecha en .NET  mediante axios ?

Comment: hola, aja , eso es lo que que quiero, dejame lo pongo en la pregunta,

Comment: listo señor espero se entienda mejor

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a la comunidad.

Te he dejado un Snippet donde puedes revisar como subir una imagen a tu api con axios,
está todo explicado correctamente,

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    nombre: "",
    fileImage: "",
    previewImage: "",
  },
  methods: {
   onImageChanged: function(event) {
      // Preview imagen
      this.fileImage = event.target.files[0];
      this.previewImage = URL.createObjectURL(this.fileImage);
    }
  },
  onUpload: function() {
  // Esto es lo que enviaremos a tu api
   let datos = {
     nombre: this.nombre,
      imagen: this.fileImage
    }
    // convertimos el array a FormData
     var formData = this.toFormData(datos);
     
     //Peticion axios con headers
       axios
              .post(
                "http://miurlapi.com",
                formData,
                {
                "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
                }
              )
              .then(response => {
               //Todo correcto a mi api
              }).catch(error => {
               console.log('tenemos errores'+error)
              });
  },
   toFormData(obj) {
   // funcion que convierte a formData
            var formData = new FormData()
            for (var key in obj) {
                formData.append(key, obj[key])
            }
            return formData
        }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label class="font-bold">Nombre: </label>
        <input
        class="form-control"
        v-model="nombre"
        name="nombre"
        placeholder="Nombre de la imagen"
    />
</div>
<div class="input-group mt-2">
        <label class="font-bold">Seleccione una imagen</label>
            <input
                type="file"
                ref="fileupload"
                accept="image/*"
                class="form-control-file"
                @change="onImageChanged"
                name="imagen"
            />
            <img
                :src="previewImage"
                class="img-thumbnail mt-2"
                v-if="fileImage"
                style="width:50%"
            />
            </div>
            <button
            class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
            @click="onUpload()"

            >
            Subir imagen
            </button>
</div>
```

Saludos!

Comment: hola señor, una pregunta, esro no seria con bit cierto? seria con una carpeta con url?

Comment: @WilberthRomero No sé como tengas un api construida, pero así mandas, si por url.

Comment: aaa bueno entonces, en la base, en vez de bit, debo tenerla en string? para guardar la url ahi? y mi segunda pregunta, como se llama la carpeta donde tienes las imagenes?

Comment: amigo, no se si contetaras jaja, vieras que estoy intentando acoplar el codigo, pero al momento de insertar la imagen, no llama al preview, mw dice que no esta referenciado\

Comment: @WilberthRomero es bastante sencillo, solamente sigue adecuadamente, lo mismos pasos que el código que te deje arriba, recuerda que debes de definir la variable preview, en tu data "previewImage"